# Select activity depending on Room

Tags: android, architecture, android-room

When I launch my app, I should select start activity, depending on Room data. Like this:

1. If there is no user (by login string, stored in preferences) - show entrance Activity.
2. If there is a user but his `propertyA` wasn't set (null by default) - show Activity where he will select it's value (non-null afterwards).
3. Otherwise show general Activity.

The first option can be easily checked, because we can load value from preferences immediately. But to check `propertyA` I need to get user by login and Room forces doing it only in background, so we need async logic here.

The options to solve this I see:

1. Show Activity from step 2 (or some temporary Activity), update to necessary when user is ready (loaded). Bad because user will see wrong contents. Moreover, to avoid unnecessary updates we should store last property value  - so we change to general Activity only when changing from null to something else (this way we get code mess for simple task).
2. Room database's `allowMainThreadQueries()`. Bad because breaks Room's general idea.
3. Semaphore (on main thread, but with expectation user loading is a fast task). Bad because looks ugly in code and has same problem as step 2.

I suppose my approach is totally wrong (in architecture way). Can you suggest how it can be solved in more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, with your issue, I wouldn't go for any of the three options you listed.

Since your app relies on fetching data before knowing what content to show to the user, why not use a Launch Screen?

Launch Screens were added to Material Design and it's a good option if you wish to do some initial start-up processing while not sacrificing aesthetics or risk displaying inaccurate data.

Here's a link to Launch Screens: https://material.io/design/communication/launch-screen.html

Even if you don't use either a Placeholder UI or a Branded Launch Screen, it's still more pleasant to just show a short animation to the User as your app queries if `propertyA` is set.